# Find the longest increasing subsequence of a given array of integers, A

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Please dont post code

find a subsequence of array in which the subsequence’s elements are in strictly increasing order, and in which the subsequence is as long as possible.
This subsequence is not necessarily contiguous, or unique.
In this case, we only care about the length of the longest increasing subsequence.

```
Input 1:
    A = [1, 2, 1, 5]

Output 1:
    3
    
Explanation 1:
    The sequence : [1, 2, 5]

Input 2:
    A = [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15]
    
Output 2:
    6

Explanation 2:
    The sequence : [0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15] or [0, 4, 6, 9, 11, 15] or [0, 4, 6, 9, 13, 15]
```

**My doubt how is this sequence formed [0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15] what will be the next number .Is this sequence[0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15] resembles anything common with this sequence [0, 4, 6, 9, 11, 15]**

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what a longest increasing subsequence is?

Comment: @Paul no i didnt understand it

Comment: @Paul i didnt understand this sequence too 0,2, 6, 9, 13, 15 what is the logic behind ths

Comment: Please do that research on your own. This site is for questions about problems with code, not for free tutoring. There's plenty of resources on the net (and also on this site). SO should be the last address when you've exhausted all other resources, not the first to dump any problem you encounter.

Comment: @paul ok paul .I respect your comment

Comment: @somanraj it is a fairly common dynamic programming problem, you can look up detailed explanations anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can't select any correct sequence for further.
But we have some comparison.
Let's assume that there are 2 lists, A and B:
if len(A) >= len(B) and A[-1] <= B[-1]:
It's better to select A than B.